# Change Emoji Appearance

Tags: emoji

Currently Wordpress displays emoji unicode symbols using an icon set like this one http://emojione.com/#gallery but to be honest I don't like how they look so I wonder if it's possible to use another icon pack that looks more native, like the one on this picture: https://en.support.wordpress.com/emoji/#emoji

Emoji icons URL now looks like https://s.w.org/images/core/emoji/2/svg/1f61a.svg

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) section says: Search, and research. I've found an [answer](https://www.nosegraze.com/customize-wordpress-emoticons/) to your question in 15 seconds.

Comment: @Max Yudin , you don't understand the question and your solution doesn't work. Please avoid giving quick answers if you're not sure you got the question. Read the section "Smileys are not Emoji" section here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Smilies

Answer (score 3):

The WP core reference lists the hooks and functions related to emoji. [Here are the hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=Emoji&post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-hook) you use to point to alternate versions of emoji.